# How to remember state with retry operators in RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a network client that is able to resume from interruptions, but needs the last message for doing so when there is a retry.

Example in Kotlin:

```
fun requestOrResume(last: Message? = null): Flowable<Message> =
    Flowable.create({ emitter ->
        val connection = if (last != null)
                             client.start()
                         else
                             client.resumeFrom(last.id)

        while (!emitter.isDisposed) {
            val msg = connection.nextMessage()
            emitter.onNext(msg)
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.MISSING)

requestOrResume()
    .retryWhen { it.flatMap { Flowable.timer(5, SECONDS) } }
    // how to pass the resume data when there is a retry?
```

**Question**: as you can see, I need the last received message in order to prepare the resume call. How can I keep track of it so that when there is a retry it is available to make the resume request?

One possible solution may be to create a holder class that just holds a reference to the last message and is updated when a new message is received. This way when there is a retry the last message can be obtained from the holder. Example:

```
class MsgHolder(var last: Message? = null)

fun request(): Flowable<Message> {
    val holder = MsgHolder()
    return Flowable.create({ emitter ->
        val connection = if (holder.last != null)
                             client.start()
                         else
                             client.resumeFrom(holder.last.id)

        while (!emitter.isDisposed) {
            val msg = connection.nextMessage()
            holder.last = msg // <-- update holder reference
            emitter.onNext(msg)
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.MISSING)
}
```

I think this might work, but it feels like a hack (thread synchronization issues?).

Is there a better way to keep track of the state so it is available for retries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, unless you rethrow a wrapper around your last element (not too functionally different from your existing "hack"-ish solution but way uglier imo), no error handling operators can recover the last element without some outside help because they only get access to streams of `Throwable`. Instead, see if the following recursive approach suits your needs:

```
fun retryWithLast(seed: Flowable<Message>): Flowable<Message> {
  val last$ = seed.last().cache();
  return seed.onErrorResumeNext {
    it.flatMap {
      retryWithLast(last$.flatMap {
        requestOrResume(it)
      })
    }
  };
}
retryWithLast(requestOrResume());
```

The biggest distinction is caching the trailing value from the last attempt in an Observable with `cache` rather than doing so manually in a value. Note also that the recursion in the error handler means `retryWithLast` will continue to extend the stream if subsequent attempts continue failing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look to `buffer()` operator: [link](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)
You could use it like this:

```
requestOrResume()
    .buffer(2)
```

From now, your `Flowable` will return `List<Message>` with two latests objects

Comment: I don't see how the `buffer` operator helps in this situation.